# What is $p$ in this candidate solution for the motion of N masses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coupled-oscillators

In this problem:

> Consider the system of $N$ masses shown in the figure (see picture 1).
>
> a) Using the approximation for small angles, write the equation of transverse movement for the n-th particle.
>
> b) Propose a solution of the form: 
>   ${ψ_n}^{(p)}(t)=A^{(p)}\cos(nk^{(p)}+α^{(p)})\cos(w^{(p)}t+\phi^{(p)})$. Find the dispersion relation and decide whether it depends on the contour conditions.
>
> **Figure 1:**
>
> [image: picture 1]
>
> **Figure 2:**
>
> [image: picture 2]

With regard to part b), I don't understand the notation of the proposed solution, to be more specific, I don't understand what $p$ is, is it an index? Could someone explain me what $\ddot{y_n}$ would be just to see what $p$ stands by?

Comment: Hi user100106, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Just checking work is off topic here, so I've removed that part from your question, but the other part is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be careful about that in future questions. By the way, do you know what $p$ stands for?

Comment: What $p$ means is that $f^{(p)}(x)$ is the $p$-th derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: I've already found out what it is, be careful, it isn't the derivative of any function. $p$ indicates the $p-th$ normal mode of the system of $N$ masses